# Pedindo Previlegios no Windows com python

Tags: python-3.x

Eu tenho meu script python, mas, preciso de privilégios de Administrador para executar uma função sem erros
ex.: apagar uma pasta.

Como faço para fazer meu script pedir privilégios a o Windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script que acha?

Answer (score 2):

[Você não pode mudar os privilégios depois de lançar uma execução no Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851413/ask-for-admin-access-for-a-python-function-in-windows). O que você precisa é garantir que a aplicação seja executado com privilégios de administrador e não como um usuário normal.

O que você pode fazer é checar os privilégios no momento em que iniciar a execução do programa e, se forem muito baixos, pedir para o usuário lançá-lo novamente, agora como administrador, ou então fazer como que o próprio programa reinicie automaticamente, porém com maiores privilégios através do `runas`.

```
import ctypes

if not ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin():
    print('Sem privilégios suficientes. Reiniciando...')
    import sys
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(
        None, 'runas', sys.executable, ' '.join(sys.argv), None, None)
    exit(0)
else:
    print('Privilégios superiores garantidos')
```